# XML to Spring Java annotation conversion

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations

I have a sample code in which I am trying to convert `application-context.xml` to Spring annotated Java class. How to add `constructor-arg` with proper annotations here. Could you please help me sort this.

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="myproject"/>

<!-- Define the SOAP version used by the WSDL -->
<bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- The location of the generated Java files -->
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="myproject.wsdl.currency"/>

<!-- Configure Spring Web Services -->
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL"/>
</bean>
 <bean id="example" class="org.project.Example"/>
```

I have created `Config.class` as below.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

@Bean(name="soapMessageFactory")
public SaajSoapMessageFactory getSoapMsgFactory() {
    SaajSoapMessageFactory soapFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
    soapFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.11);
    return soapFactory;
}

@Bean(name="webServiceTemplate")
public WebServiceTemplate getWsTemplate(Marshaller marshaller, Unmarshaller unmarshaller) {
    WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    //how to configure the constructor-arg here
    wsTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    wsTemplate.setUnMarshaller(unmarshaller);
    wsTemplate.setDefaultUri(http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL);
    return wsTemplate;
}

@Bean(name="example")
public Example getExample() {
   return new ExampleImpl();
```

}

Comment: `new WebServiceTemplate(getSoapMsgFactory());` Or you could pass it as argument to the method as you're already doing for the marshaller and the unmarshaller.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
@Bean(name="soapMessageFactory")
public SaajSoapMessageFactory getSoapMsgFactory() {
    SaajSoapMessageFactory soapFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
    soapFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.11);
    return soapFactory;
}

@Bean(name="webServiceTemplate")
public WebServiceTemplate getWsTemplate(SaajSoapMessageFactory soapFactory, Marshaller marshaller, Unmarshaller unmarshaller) {
    WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(soapFactory);
    wsTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    wsTemplate.setUnMarshaller(unmarshaller);
    wsTemplate.setDefaultUri(http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL);
    return wsTemplate;
}
```

When you specify any dependecy in `@Bean` method, spring will search for that bean in its context.

Since `SaajSoapMessageFactory` is locally created and doesn't have any other dependency, you could just call it locally like this

```
  WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(getSoapMsgFactory());
```